# Error: Imported Content is empty in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I’m trying to automatically pull information from a website into my Google Sheets but I’m facing some challenges.

I’m trying to extract information from below page, especially the Piotroski value:
https://www.gurufocus.com/term/fscore/NYSE:ABBV/Piotroski-F-Score/AbbVie

In particular, this class:

```
<p class="term_cal"><strong>Piotroski F-Score is 7, indicating very healthy situation.</strong></p>
```

Or this 7 (as of today) from:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12" id="def_body_detail_height">
<h1 style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700; display: inline;"> AbbVie Piotroski F-Score </h1><font style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700; color: #337ab7">: 7 (As of Today)</font>
```

I tried below function, but receiving `Could not fetch URL` as error message

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.gurufocus.com/term/fscore/NYSE:ABBV/Piotroski-F-Score/AbbVie","//p[@class='term_cal']")
```

Also, tried on a different website:
https://www.macroaxis.com/invest/ratio/ABBV--Piotroski-F-Score

For the following class:

```
<div class="scoreValue">7</div>
```

With following function:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.macroaxis.com/invest/ratio/ABBV--Piotroski-F-Score","//div[@class='scoreValue']")
```

Now, I’m getting `Imported Content is empty` as error message.

Comment: Unfortunately Google Sheets ```IMPORTXML``` only works with static content so content loaded dynamically by a script might not be able to be obtained. Are you open to a workaround using Apps Script class [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)?

Comment: Hi Mateo, 

Thanks for your reply.

Yes, I realized it won't work with a simple IMPORTXML so I'm now trying to create a custom function with a script in Google Sheets using the UrlFetchApp but I'm not sure how to properly capture the different classes I want.

Someone helped me with this piece of code but I don't know how to adapt it:
function getFScoreTextGab(url) {

let d = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

var regex_find_class = new RegExp("<p.*class=.term_cal.*[\n]+.*?</p>");
//var regex_find_html = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
  
var term_cal = regex_find_class.exec(d)

return term_cal[0]

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have indicated that you would be well with an Apps Script solution using [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl) I am proving here such a solution to get your desired value (7).

The following piece of code has explanatory comments. You were really close to get this working:

```js
function getFScoreTextGab() {
  var url = 'https://www.macroaxis.com/invest/ratio/ABBV--Piotroski-F-Score';
  
  // Get the content of that site as a string
  var d = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  
  // String to search (in your case following the class value)
  // Note that the string to be search contains 19 characters
  var search = 'class="scoreValue">'; 
  // Get the index where the data we are interested is found in the string
  var index = d.search(search);
  // Get the character at that index (plus 19 is because search returns the
  // index of the first character of the search, in this case it would return
  // the index of c (of class) and therefore we must add to the index the length
  // of our string
  var value = d.charAt(index+search.length);
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Hello Mateo,

thank you very much for helping me out.

I created a Google Script thanks to your code, I saved it & ran it after granting authorizations.

When I try to call the function getFScoreTextGab in the Sheets, I don't get answer.
If I understand correctly, this function doesn't need any parameter when you call it.
I tried to call it with the following  = getFScoreTextGab ()

2 questions: 
- what step am I missing here?
- how can we adjust the function to pass the ticker for example ABBV in parameter when call the function please?

Thanks again :)
Gabriel

Comment: That is because I am only logging the output. I have edited it so that it returns the right value in the cell I believe. Let me know if that works. :)

Comment: It works with the return (value). That's beautiful :) Thank you !!!

Sorry, 2 follow-up questions:
- how can we change the code to enter the ticker ABBV in parameter of the function to dynamically generate the URL please?

- in the same project, I try to extract a number from a field but this number changes size & format ($63,284 Mil, $386 Mil, $192.7 Mil or $71.9 Mil), I'm trying to figure out how to properly use regextract function for that with REGEXEXTRACT(E19,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+") but I get an error message for $386 Mil as there is no , or .

Thanks again :)   
Gab

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve:

$63,284 Mil  63,284 REGEXEXTRACT(E22,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+")
$3,552 Mil  3,552 REGEXEXTRACT(E23,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+")
$386 Mil          #N/A REGEXEXTRACT(E24,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+")
$192.7 Mil  192.7 REGEXEXTRACT(E25,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+")
$71.9 Mil           71.9 REGEXEXTRACT(E62,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+")

Thank you :)

Comment: I found the answer to the 2nd question with regexreplace(E22, "[^0-9,.]",)

Comment: Hi ! As these other two questions are not directly related to the original question you posted, you will need to create new questions for them in Stack Overflow according to [their guidelines and best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which helps to bring renewed attention and to keep each question focused on a single issue. Also, if my solution solved your problem consider accepting it so that other members of the community with similar issues can easily find it. Thanks ! :D

Comment: Hi Mateo,
sorry, I'm very new to StackOverflow. How can I accept your answer as a solution?
Could you help me to adjust your function to have the ticker in parameter of the function please?
Thanks again :)

Comment: You already did :D What do you mean by having the ticker in the parameter of the function? Do you mean to pass the URL as a parameter?

Comment: Hi Mateo,
Yes, ideally my idea would be to pass the URL & the class name in parameters of the function to retrieve multiple fields from different URL.
Thanks helping for your super valuable help

Comment: Hi Mateo, I modified your script (as I edited in my original post) to pass the URL in parameter when calling the function.

How can pass have the class name as a 2nd parameter when calling the function please?

Thank you

Comment: Hi ! To pass a second parameter (the classname) you would just need to pass it as a second parameter in the function ```function XMLScraper (url,class) {``` and then add it in  in the search variable like this ```var search = 'class="'+class+'">';```. Note in this last modification the ```'``` sign before and after the class parameter. Hope this solves all your questions :D

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I modified my script thanks to your comments but I get an error message ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'class' (line 1, file "Code.gs") ``` on the first line ```function ScraperClass (url,class) {``` & I also modified line 12 to use the class parameter for the variable ```  var search = 'class="'+class+'">';```

Comment: Hi again Mateo, also, if I remove class as a parameter in the line line like that ```function ScraperClass (url) {``` then I get an error message ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token '+' (line 12, file "Code.gs")``` at line 12 ```  var search = 'class="'+class+'">';``` so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong :/

Comment: Sorry, my bad, class should not be used in Javascript as it is saved for internal functions of the language itself. Change your parameter ```class``` for ```className```. I.e ```function ScraperClass (url,className) {``` and ```var search = 'class="' + className + '">';```. Let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: Big thanks, it's working now. I will try it on multiple websites but at least on this one, it's working :)