# Using IMPORTXML in Google Sheets to scrape data from Transfermarkt

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to see if it's possible to scrape data from Transfermarkt.com to import into a Google Sheets doc.

Currently, I'm trying to import the team data from a player's profile page (see example URL here: https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/joao-palhinha/profil/spieler/257455) but in future may want to import other data as well.

I wonder if it's possible to scrape data in this way from Transfermarkt, but if it is, any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be very much appreciated!

Right now I'm using, =IMPORTXML(B1,"/html/body/div[3]/main/header/div[4]/div/span[1]/a") where the URL is in B1. I copied the Full XPath from the HTML, but have also tried this by copying just the XPath too.

It says Loading for a few seconds before returning N/A, with an error message 'Resource at URL not found'.

I'm expecting the result in this instance to be Fulham.

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected value. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected values? And, the URL you want to use is only `https://stackoverflow.com/users/21238352/bevans`?

Comment: Hi, to simplify the question, I want to be able to scrape the data from this URL (https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/joao-palhinha/profil/spieler/257455) so that the club the footballer plays for, in this case Fulham, appears in my Google Sheet if that makes sense?

I tried using IMPORTXML and copying the XPath, but instead of the result being 'Fulham', it's N/A with the error message 'Resource at URL not found'.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal in this question, you want to retrieve a value of `Fulham` from the URL of `https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/joao-palhinha/profil/spieler/257455`. Is my understanding correct? First, I am trying to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: According to this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726694/error-imported-content-is-empty-in-google-sheets IMPORTXML in Google Sheets is only able to fetch data from static websites. An excellent solution was proposed by https://stackoverflow.com/users/15019380/mike-steelson is to create an script using UrlFetchApp, please check his response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72316608/google-sheets-importxml-resource-at-url-not-found-is-this-possible-at-all?rq=1 The documentation for UrlFetchApp could be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch